# Is it possible to shorten my if elif statements to assign a variable value within each if condition? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

Here's the code I am using.

```
if i < 50:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_A")
elif i >= 50 and i < 100:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_B")
elif i >= 100 and i < 150:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_C")
elif i >= 150 and i < 200:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_D")
elif i >= 200 and i < 250:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_E")
elif i >= 250 and i < 300:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_F")
elif i >= 300 and i < 350:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_G")
elif i >= 350 and i < 400:
    test_a = os.getenv("TEST_VAR_H")
else:
    test_a = "test"
```

Is it possible to shorten it? Say in one line?

Thanks!

Comment: I like to always rearrange my code so it can use `<=` and `<` and never  `>=` and `>`. In languages without ranges, it buys you a range-like syntax, that almost reads like math: `100 < i and i <150`. But in Python, you can even do `100 < i < 150`!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python ranges can clean this up pretty well. There are various ways you can pull this off in a few line,s but they're probably just worse. For example:

```py
def get_test_var(i): # Name this something better.
    try:
        letter = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'][i // 50]
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_" + letter)
    except IndexError:
        return "test"
```

Although admittedly, if somebody used environment variables named `"TEST_VAR_A"`, I might just get into a homicidal rage.

Depending on what your real use case is, I think the "manual" solution is a bit more verbose, but much easier to understand and to change. For example, if you ever want to have non-equal intervals (say, 125-200), the previous approach would fail entirely.

People shouldn't need test cases or a debugger to trace out what your code does. It should be obvious at a glance.

```py
def get_test_var(i): # Name this something better.
    if i in range(0, 50):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_A")
    elif i in range(50, 100):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_B")
    elif i in range(100, 150):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_C")
    elif i in range(150, 200):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_D")
    elif i in range(200, 250):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_E")
    elif i in range(250, 300):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_F")
    elif i in range(300, 350):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_G")
    elif i in range(350, 400):
        return os.getenv("TEST_VAR_H")
    else:
        return "test"
```

Comment: Shouldn't "TEST_VAR_H" be "TEST_VAR_" so when you append the letter it's not "TEST_VAR_HA", "HB", etc?

Comment: @Alexander Deep breaths...channel your rage to good and find your happy place. 

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, that was a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @Ethan I'll be in my good and happy place when people stop using environment variables :)

Comment: Oh, also floor divide on your `i/50` -> `i//50`

Comment: @HenryEcker That only makes a difference for floats, right?

Comment: list indexes have to be whole numbers. So like if `i` was 15, `i/50 = 0.3` which would raise a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float` while `i//50 = 0` which would produce "A" as expected.

Comment: @HenryEcker Classic, I was running in python 2 mode by accident hahah